# Angular: HTTP POST with multiple Parameters not working

Tags: java, angular, spring, http, spring-data-jpa

My Frontend is made with Angular. Backend is made with Java Spring.

I have two entities `essen(meal)` and `essensplan (mealplan)`. Each `essensplan` consists of five objects of `essen`, configured as ManyToMany Relationship in Java Spring.

The Template displays every object of `essen` in a selectbox. With `[ngValue]="essen"` I pass the object `essen` to the method `addEssenToEssensplan` in my component and service.

**essensplan-detail.component.html**

```
<form *ngIf="essensplan">
 <div class="form-group">
  <select [(ngModel)]="essen" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <option *ngFor="let essen of speisekarte" [ngValue]="essen" label="{{essen.name}}"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <button (click)="addEssenToEssensplan(essen)" type="button" class="btn btn- 
    primary">Hinzufügen</button>
</form>
```

**essensplan-detail.component.ts**

```
  addEssenToEssensplan(essen: Essen): void {
    this.essensplanService.addEssenToEssensplan(this.essensplan, essen);
  }
```

**essensplan.service.ts**

```
  addEssenToEssensplan(essensplan: Essensplan | number, essen: Essen): Observable<Essen> {
    const essensplanId = typeof essensplan === 'number' ? essensplan : essensplan.id;
    const currentEssen = essen;
    const url = `${this.essensplanUrl}/${essensplanId}/add`;
    const data = {id: essensplanId, essen: currentEssen};
    return this.http.post<Essen>(url, data);
  }
```

**Controller in Java Spring**

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/{id}/add")
    public void addEssenToEssensplan(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody Essen essen) {
        essensplanService.addEssenToEssensplan(id, essen);
    }
```

**Service:**

```
    @Transactional
    public Essensplan addEssenToEssensplan(int id, Essen essen) {

        Optional<Essensplan> optionalEssensplan = essensplanRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalEssensplan.isPresent()) {
             Essensplan essensplan = optionalEssensplan.get();
            essensplan.getEssenProWoche().add(essen);
            return essensplan;
        } else return null;
    }
```

I already made a POST Request via Postman Client with for example `http://localhost:8080/essensplan/2/add` and it worked. For me it seems like the POST Request does not reach my Java Spring Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your data object. You do not need to put `essensplanId` there. It is not part of the request body but a PathVariable.

Try :

```
    addEssenToEssensplan(essensplan: Essensplan | number, essen: Essen): Observable<Essen> {
        const essensplanId = typeof essensplan === 'number' ? essensplan : essensplan.id;
        return this.http.post<Essen>(`${this.essensplanUrl}/${essensplanId}/add`, {essen});
    }
```

Edit :

You also need to subscribe to your observable at some time or else the request will never be executed :

```
  addEssenToEssensplan(essen: Essen): void {
    this.essensplanService.addEssenToEssensplan(this.essensplan, essen).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: thanks, that made my code much cleaner. but sadly it still does not work. :(

Comment: There does not even appear an error. Not in the browser console and not  in the console of the backend. The url for the post request should be fine tough. The method in my controller still does not get called.

Comment: I also console.log `essen` and the url. both are correct.